# Modular Program using Config files

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, ini

I'm being tasked with making a modular program that uses external, easy to edit files to dictate if certain elements are shown, what classes are used, etc.

Using C# and Visual Studio 2008, what type of file should I use? I was suggested .ini, but there is also talk of using .xml for it?

Which file would be best, and is there a built-in C# method of working with those files?

Answer (score 1):

There's a heap of different ways for achieving different things.  You could for example use an appSetting in an app.config file to turn features on and off.  If you wanted to change classes or services that are used, then you could use DI/IoC with something like [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/) and configure that in code and or xml.

If you can be more specific with what you want to achieve, and some examples in code, you can probably get some better answers.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not really allowed to post this code. A better example, I suppose, would be that, at launch, it reads an XML file, or some configuration file, and the program chooses classes and what controls to display based on that file. Reading it in with a loop is something I thought of trying, but I wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: If you need to change what classes are used, that sounds like a case for IoC to me.  Take a look at Windsor, Ninject and DI/IoC containers.  If you classes implemented an interface you could use Windsor etc to swap out and specify the concrete class you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom sections in your config files. 
Config files are xml, well known files in .net context.
See example here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)